# FB.Canvas.setSize stopped working (today?)

Tags: tabs, facebook-canvas

This method seems to have stopped working.

App code was tested thoroughly last week and all was well.   This morning...scrollbars are appearing on our page tab apps.

Example:
http://www.facebook.com/HondaPowersports/app_329359370439338

Very simple code on this page - it is all static HTML with just one FB method call:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 975 });
}
```

Anyone else with this same problem?   Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation ([FB.Canvas.setSize](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/)):

> Note: this method is only enabled when Canvas Height is set to "Settable (Default: 800px)" in the Developer App.

Has someone modified the settings of your Facebook app? If it's not configured as stated above then it stops working.

Comment: Yep all of these basics are already covered.   Literally nothing has changed, I am the only person with access to these settings.  Canvas is still set to fluid.

Comment: Also btw this is for a tab on a profile page, not a regular app canvas

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me it is deprecated and you have to use setAutoGrow... not sure , take a look :)

Comment: ok well apparently facebook has fixed the bug through no action of mine.   thanks guys for trying to help.

Comment: it's not deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/

Answer (score 0):

Related bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/322561887802154